# JS bitwise XOR operator acts differently from PHP’s counterpart. How to get the same result as PHP returns?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, bitwise-operators, bitwise-xor

Is it true that JS bitwise XOR operator acts differently from PHP’s counterpart? I receive different result of the same operation in JS and PHP.

This is PHP code. Final array contains exactly result if XOR bitwise operator `^` character by character. And it is different from Node.js bitwise XOR:

```
$b = hex2bin('db6dc3f86800da4f7c19e643e8941ebb');
$md5raw = md5($b, TRUE);

/* for the sake of verification with JS - the result is the same */
$h = bin2hex($md5raw); // => b885730327999e8823d113161c3538d3


$string = "1234567";
$string .= "\x00";
$len = 16;

$result = '';
$arr = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) {
    $result .= $string[$i] ^ $md5raw[$i % $len];
    array_push($arr, bin2hex($result));
}

print_r(bin2hex($result)); // => 89b7403712afa988
Array
(
    [0] => 89
    [1] => 89b7
    [2] => 89b740
    [3] => 89b74037
    [4] => 89b7403712
    [5] => 89b7403712af
    [6] => 89b7403712afa9
    [7] => 89b7403712afa988
)
```

And this is Node.js equvalent of PHP code above. This is link for the code https://repl.it/JjPV/0. But it doesn't work in that compiler for some reason. However it works fine with local Node.js installation.

This is a code w/o functions (to save space here; functions are in the `repl.it` link). And result of bitwise is different. Why is it so? How to make it the same as PHP returns?

```
let b = hex2bin('db6dc3f86800da4f7c19e643e8941ebb');
let md5hex = md5(b);  // => b885730327999e8823d113161c3538d3
let md5raw = new Buffer(md5hex, "hex").toString('binary'); // to raw binary like in PHP md5(val, TRUE);

let string = "1234567"
string += "\x00";
let len = 16;

let result = '';
let arr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    result += string[i] ^ md5raw[i % len];
    arr.push(bin2hex(result));
}

console.log(bin2hex(result)) // => 31313031313132353733
console.log(arr);
[ '31',
  '313130',
  '3131303131',
  '313130313131',
  '31313031313132',
  '3131303131313235',
  '313130313131323537',
  '31313031313132353733' ]
```

Comment: @Morgan, thanks for the link, but that doesn't solvethe problem. So, it is apparently not a duplicate question

Comment: Remove this part: `.toString('binary')`

Comment: @harold, I did. It doesn't help

Comment: Maybe not but that part is certainly wrong, you're not supposed to be working with a string in base 2 but rather with the actual bytes. I can't run the code so for the rest it's hard to tell.