# PHP Bitwise XOR vs. JavaScript Bitwise XOR

Tags: javascript, php, binary, bitwise-operators, xor

I'm trying to find a way to make `PHP Bitwise XOR` results match the results of `JavaScript Bitwise XOR`. I came across different questions of this issue, and all without answers. Here are a few of them:

[Javascript & PHP Xor equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24154381/javascript-php-xor-equivalent)

[php bitwise XOR and js bitwise XOR producing different results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39234130/php-bitwise-xor-and-js-bitwise-xor-producing-different-results)

[JS bitwise XOR operator acts differently from PHP’s counterpart. How to get the same result as PHP returns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45327920/js-bitwise-xor-operator-acts-differently-from-php-s-counterpart-how-to-get-the?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I know that PHP is using 64 bit compared to 32 bit JavaScript, but my question is, is there any manual way to count similar results? How can we make PHP get similar results as JS?

If the numbers are short, the results will always be the same in JS and PHP, However, if the numbers are long, the issue happens. Example:

```js
var a = 234324234232;
var b = 221312312232;
console.log(a^b);
```

JS Output:

```
166587472
```

PHP Code:

```
$a = 234324234232;
$b = 221312312232;
echo $a^$b;
```

PHP Output:

```
21641423952
```

---

Sometimes JavaScript gives negative results:

```js
var a = 202338273;
var b = 523511134400;
console.log(a^b);
```

JS Output

```
-272722143
```

PHP Code:

```
$a = 202338273;
$b = 523511134400;
echo $a^$b;
```

PHP Output:

```
523713287969
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mask to a signed int.

```
$c = ($a ^ $b) & 0xffffffff;
if ($c & 0x80000000)
  $c -= 0x100000000;
echo $c;
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, Thanks!